# How to root Samsung Galaxy S4 value edition i9515?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

My father brought me this smart phoe and when I search on Internet chat with my friends i9500 and 505 are common but mine i.e.19515 is differnt and I dont have idea  to root it.
I have tried srsroot and motochopper. But no work

Help me out

Comment: What errors do you get from SRSRoot or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to root Samsung Galaxy S4 GT-I9515L running Android 4.4.2 by following the steps in [CF-Auto-Root](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2219803) and using the datafiles in CF-Auto-Root-jflte-jfltexx-gti9505.zip

These are the steps in the link:

> - Download and unzip the CF-Auto-Root-....zip file (see posts below this one)
> - If you end up with a recovery.img and cache.img file, you've extracted twice. You need to end up with a .tar.md5 file - don't
>     extract that one
> - (USB) Disconnect your phone from your computer
> - Start Odin3-vX.X.exe
> - Click the PDA button, and select CF-Auto-Root-....tar.md5 (**Note**: PDA was renamed to AP in the current version of Odin3)
> - Put your phone in download mode (turn off phone, then hold VolDown+Home+Power to boot - if it asks you to press a button to
>     continue, press the listed button, or run adb reboot download command)
> - (USB) Connect the phone to your computer
> - Make sure Repartition is NOT checked
> - Click the Start button
> - Wait for Android to boot
> - Done (if it took you more than 30 seconds, you need practise!)